# Cocoa Swift: Connect Main Menu to Preferences Window Controller & Disabling Items like Minimise in Attributes Inspector doesn't work in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4

I have a simple Menubar app in which it has 2 options - namely **Preferences** & **Quit**

After clicking on **Preferences** it opens a new window but doesn't show the menu bar

I tried connecting from Main Menu to the Window Controller but it doesn't work.

I drag it from the Application Name to the Window Controller or View Controller using Ctrl+Drag but still it doesn't work.

Another issue is my Preferences Window is resizing even though I unchecked the resize button in the Attributes Inspector.

Even Maximise & Minimise checkboxes are disabled but they are still showing.

Any solutions?

Comment: macOS windows do not show a "menu bar". The Main Menu is the menu for the entire application. If you're writing an accessory app that puts a status menu item in the top-right menu bar (and does not appear in the dock), then it has no main menu. (Accessory apps are never the active app.) UI controls that have a `menu` property/outlet are typically contextual menus (menus that pop-up when you right-click on something); these do not appear in the menu bar.

Comment: As for window resizing, make sure the constraints for your layout fixes the size of the enclosing window, and the cumulative priority is higher than 500 (the window resizing priority). Turning off the window min/max controls does not make them go away, they just appear disabled (grey).

Comment: @JamesBucanek I don't know what its called but on the right top where we have File, Edit, View, etc.. I want that to show up when I open Preferences window but it doesn't show up. I don't know how to connect it properly. I tried CTRL+DRAG but failed. As for window resizing, there are no constraints. I have the Window Controller & View Controller of the same size ,i.e, 416x214.

Comment: At the top *left*, the File, Edit, View, etc. is the main menu bar. Again, if you're writing an accessory app this will never appear; accessory apps are never the active app and the top menu bar always belongs to the active app.

Comment: @JamesBucanek I don't understand accessory apps. I am writing a Menu Bar app which will run in background. But there is also an app called http://heyfocus.com & its a menu bar app but when Preferences is clicked it shows the Main Menu bar. I want mine to work like that.

Comment: Yes, a background app is called an *accessory app*.

Comment: Hey @JamesBucanek thanks for all the help. I looked into it & I couldn't figure it out so I went with the solution I posted below. Now I can open my Preferences window properly, without minimise, maximise & resizing buttons enabled & it doesn't show Main Menu Bar as some popular apps like Dropbox Desktop went that way so I also chose that path.

Answer (score 2):

See `NSApplication.activationPolicy`.

If you want the app's main menu bar to appear, you'll need to change the `activationPolicy` to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`. Once you do that, the app's main menu will appear when your app is the active one. (It will also appear in the dock.)

If you want this to happen only when your preferences window is open, then you'll need to change the `activationPolicy` when the window opens, then set it back again when it closes.

You don't need to connect any outlets for this; the Main Menu should already be a resource for your app and should be loaded automatically when your app launches.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had given **Storyboard Id** to my **View Controller** rather than my **Window Controller** so it wasn't working.

I also checked some apps like Dropbox which didn't have Main Menu Bar because it was a background or accessory app so I ditched it.

Some apps like [Focus](https://heyfocus.com) have it though. But I went with the popular choice.

As for no resizing, no minimising & no maximising goes, I pasted below code & it worked

```
var myWindow: NSWindow? = nil
myWindow?.styleMask.remove(NSWindow.StyleMask.resizable)
myWindow?.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isEnabled=false
myWindow?.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isEnabled=false
```